# Testing Service Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I am facing a problem with I have no clue how to solve it beacause I am so noobie with testing in front.

Right now I am testing a service that have this code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { EndpointLocatorService } from './endpointLocator.service';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class CancelAppService {

    constructor(private readonly http: Http,
        private readonly _endPointLocator: EndpointLocatorService) { }

    getScopeSignature(signatureToken: string) {
        const url = this._endPointLocator.locate('cancelApp');
        const language = sessionStorage.getItem('languageSession');
        const headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept-Language': language,
            'X-B3-TraceId': sessionStorage.getItem('requestID')
        });
        const body = JSON.stringify({ 'signatureToken': signatureToken });
        return this.http.post(url, body, { headers }).map(data => {
            return data.json();
        }).catch((error: any) => {
            return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
        });
    }
}
```

The testing file contains this:

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { CancelAppService } from './cancelApp.service';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { EndpointLocatorService } from './endpointLocator.service';
import { AppConfig } from '../app.config';
import 'jasmine';

fdescribe('CancelAppService', () => {
    let cancelService: CancelAppService; // Add this
    let endLocator: EndpointLocatorService;
    const mockData = {
        "signature_token": "returnedToken"
    };
    const body = JSON.stringify({ 'signatureToken': 'givenToken' });
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                HttpModule
            ],
            providers: [
                CancelAppService,
                AppConfig,
                EndpointLocatorService
            ]
        });
        cancelService = TestBed.get(CancelAppService); // Add this
        endLocator = TestBed.get(EndpointLocatorService);
    });

    it('should be created', () => { // Remove inject()
        expect(cancelService).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should call the service', () => {
        spyOn(endLocator, 'locate').and.returnValue('someUrl');
        spyOn(cancelService, 'getScopeSignature').and.callThrough();
        cancelService.getScopeSignature(body);
        expect(cancelService.getScopeSignature).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it('should return a object', () => {
        (done: DoneFn) => {
            spyOn(endLocator, 'locate').and.returnValue('someUrl');
            spyOn(cancelService, 'getScopeSignature').and.returnValue(mockData);
            cancelService.getScopeSignature(body).subscribe(data => {
                expect(data).toEqual(mockData);
                done();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that, when I try to test the returned data map, appears me like a success test, but the coverage says that I have no coveraged the lines of map, and catch.

[image]

Any idea what am I doing wrong? and how to solve it?

Thank you so much!!

Comment: whats your cli version

Comment: "@angular/cli": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.14",

Comment: Where are you faking the call so it goes to go the catch block?

Comment: @JuanMendes I dont upload here that block of code, cause I prefer to know how to test first the .map() part and try to figure out how to do the catch :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mocking the service being tested, you should mock the service being used by your service `EndpointLocatorService` and maybe even  `HttpClient` to minimize mocking. You can verify that by stepping through your code.

Let me explain in the code why those lines are not hit.

```
// In this example, the lines are hit, but after the test exited.
it('should call the service', () => {
    spyOn(endLocator, 'locate').and.returnValue('someUrl');
    spyOn(cancelService, 'getScopeSignature').and.callThrough();
    // Here you are calling a method yourself and checking that it was
    // called, it doesn't make sense, this test should make sure
    // You should check that your endLocator was called.
    // Note that because you are not waiting for the promise to resolve,
    // The test finishes before either callback is handled.
    cancelService.getScopeSignature(body);
    expect(cancelService.getScopeSignature).toHaveBeenCalled();
});


// In this example the lines in your test are never hit because you
// mocked it
it('should return a object', () => {
    (done: DoneFn) => {
        spyOn(endLocator, 'locate').and.returnValue('someUrl');
        // Here you are mocking getScopeSignature completely so it doesn't
        // Run any of your lines that you are trying to test
        // It just tests that you mocked it correctly
        spyOn(cancelService, 'getScopeSignature').and.returnValue(mockData);
        cancelService.getScopeSignature(body).subscribe(data => {
            expect(data).toEqual(mockData);
            done();
        });
    }
});
```

I can't rewrite your test so it actually tests it because it depends on how the `EndpointLocatorService` works and you may choose to mock it at that level also. I typically choose to mock at the `HttpClient` level since I can copy paste responses from the network tab.

The point is that you need to mock services used by your service, not the service itself. You have the option to mock the direct services used by your component, or you can mock at a deeper level. For example, your `EndpointLocatorService` may need to call `HttpClient` and you could choose to mock either service.

See https://angular.io/guide/testing#httpclienttestingmodule and https://alligator.io/angular/testing-httpclient/

Comment: Hmm so what you are saying in the first case is that i should do the expect like: expect(endLocator.locate).toHaveBeenCalled(); and after that the code that i have with cancelService ?

Comment: Your question was why you didn't get coverage and I explained that it's because you mocked the service itself. Unfortunately, converting your code to properly test is not something that can be done with one or two lines. You should understand how to test services that call `HttpClient` as I suggested. See the links in the answer. The idea is that if you mock all the XHR calls that made, you don't need to mock anything else (Not even your locator service) and you can just call your components's API and check its result. You can choose a mix but we do it at the HttpClient for consistency

Comment: For the first one, you don't typically need to make sure that `locate` was called because you are mocking it, so the rest of the of the code should just work and your assertion would make sure of that. But there's nothing bad about making sure it was called. I always prefer to test the API itself, instead of making sure a method was called.

Comment: Do the reading, try it out. If you can't get it to work. Post a new question with what you tried after learning about HttpClient testing and link it to this one so I get a notification

Comment: Thanks, I'll try, hehehe, this is new to me and a bit confusing.

Comment: This is pretty common when first learning to write tests, good thing you caught the problem with the coverage report, otherwise your successful tests would be misleading. Once you rewrite this, it'll never happen again (mocking the service itself) but there you still need to be careful so you don't leave pending AJAX requests after your test finishes.